# How to use VBA to read the values of a checkbox from an Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I have created a userform that contains two checkboxes.  I would like to be able to do different things depending on whether each box is checked or unchecked.  However, it seems like no matter what I do, it will always tell me the original value of the checkboxes (false and false).  Here is the code attached to clicking CommandButton1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ReadData

End Sub
```

And here ReadData:

```
Sub ReadData()

Dim myForm As UserForm
Set myForm = UserForms.Add("ComplaintEntryForm")

Debug.Print (myForm!CheckBox1.Name)
Debug.Print (myForm!CheckBox1.Value)
Debug.Print (myForm!CheckBox2.Name)
Debug.Print (myForm!CheckBox2.Value)

End Sub
```

No matter how the boxes are checked, the immediate window always shows this:

```
VBA.UserForms.Add("ComplaintEntryForm").Show
CheckBox1
False
CheckBox2
False
```

I have a screenshot of the whole operation but it won't let me upload it because I'm a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method to load and show the form (this goes in a normal module):

```
Sub main()

Dim myForm As ComplaintEntryForm

Set myForm = New ComplaintEntryForm
myForm.Show
Set myForm = Nothing

End Sub
```

In the UserForm's own module, add the following:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

readData

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()

readData

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.CheckBox1.Value = True
Me.CheckBox2.Value = False

End Sub

Private Sub readData()

Debug.Print Me.CheckBox1.Name
Debug.Print Me.CheckBox1.Value
Debug.Print Me.CheckBox2.Name
Debug.Print Me.CheckBox2.Value

End Sub
```

I've initialized the two checkboxes to specific values in the `Initialize` event. This means we are certain about the state the form will start in

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the response; that works perfectly. I was just trying to avoid having to enter too much code in the UserForm's own module since I'm creating the UserForm on the fly, and the only way I know how to add code to the UserForm is like this:
With TempForm.CodeModule
.InsertLines 1, "Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
.InsertLines 2, "'Do stuff"
.InsertLines 3, "End Sub"
End With
Which is a pain, especially with quotations.  But it turned out I only needed like 18 lines, so that was okay.  Thank you very much for your help!