# Checkboxes to print specific pages

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I'm trying to create a Word document where on the first page there are checkboxes to select/deselect pages to print.

I'm trying to write some sort of macro that will return a value (page number) that I can use in `Application.PrintOut pages="(checkbox values)"` to print the document to check when `checkbox.value = true`.

But I'm unsure how to go about it, or if it's even do-able.

Comment: `I'm trying to write some sort of macro` Post what you've wrote so far.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379613/how-to-use-vba-to-read-the-values-of-a-checkbox-from-an-excel-userform

Comment: It's not really a question of whether or not it is doable, more whether it is feasible and even if it's the right approach in the first place. As @findwindow says [waves] you need to show what you have attempted so far. Are you planning to add the textboxes manually, or do you want them to be automatically generated for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've got to add something like

```
Dim PagesToPrint As String
If checkbox.value = True Then
    PagesToPrint = "1"
End If
```

For each checkbox... Then you'd have to change the following

```
Application.PrintOut pages="(checkbox values)"
```

To

```
Application.PrintOut pages:=PagesToPrint
```

It would be useful though to have a little more information. For example the code that you already have.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I had to change 
Application.PrintOut pages:=PagesToPrint 
to
Application.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:=PagesToPrint

and now i can build on the document and it works perfectly!
Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! I'm happy to help anyway I can because I know how hard it is to find a solution to a specific problem sometimes ;) CU around